# sys/select.h для windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw

Хочу перенести свою программу под винду с линукса, но возникла проблема: программа использует `sys/select.h`, а конкретнее, вот такую функцию:

```
int input()
{
fd_set rfds;
struct timeval tv;
int retval;
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(0, &rfds);
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 100;
retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
if (retval)
    return getch();
else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что проблема с `select`? Может все же с `getch()`? Впрочем, лучше просто приведите вывод компилятора/линкера, свидетельствующий о проблеме (а также вывод `uname -a`)

Comment: Странно. Что у вас за Linux? Я проверил (заменив getch на getchar) и в `uname -a; cat /etc/issue
Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-122-generic #146-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 23 15:34:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS \n \l` все не только компилируется, но даже работает. Кстати, у меня достаточно включать только `stdlib.h` и `stdio.h`

Comment: @avp ах, да, там опечатка. Только сейчас заметил: не под линукс, а под винду с линукса.

Comment: ЕМНИП под win `select()` работает только с сокетами... для обычных файловых дескрипторов (в том числе для терминалов) в WIN API должен быть свой механизм неблокирующего IO, но на вскидку, как он зовётся не скажу...

Comment: да, если `getch ()` из curses'а, то почему бы не сделать всё его средствами — просто установив `timeout()`?

Comment: @Fat-Zer а не подскажете что за timeout? К сожалению я так и не нашел подробной литературы по curses на русском, так что знания у меня по нему весьма общие.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, timeout(n) заставляет getch() возвращать ERR через n миллисекунд, если не было ввода. При этом под капотом ncurses по факту делает тоже самое, что и ты (только с `poll ()`/`read ()`), а в `pdcurses` должна быть своя реализация... Правда разрешения до 100 микросекунд не получить, но обычно на пользовательском вводе точность больше миллисекунды избыточна… В итоге получится что-то типа [такого](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/pIEl72NDV3UAWunin4TD/)… Конечно если ввод происходит только в одном месте, а `timeout()` всегда нужен, то можно просто установить его и не отключать.

Comment: Фича эта относительно нишевая, поэтому в книжках (и всяких HOWTO) она вряд ли описана, разве что между делом упомянута в абзаце про `getch()`, а документация (маны) к ncurses AFAIK пока не переведена на русский. так что остаётся только общий [`man 3x timeout`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=timeout&category=3&russian=1)

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо!!! Очень помогли. Оформите, пожалуйста как ответ, это поможет другим, кто будет просматривать вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании getch () из curses'а, можно обойтись средствами оного, установив [`timeout()`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=timeout&category=3&russian=1). Примерно аналогичное поведение коду в вопросе будет обеспечивать следующий отрывок:

```
int input()
{
    int rv;
    timeout (10); // 10 ms block
    rv = getch();
    timeout (-1)  // turn off timeout
    return rv!= ERR ? rv : 0;
}
```

`timeout(n)` заставляет getch() возвращать ERR через n миллисекунд, если не было ввода. Правда разрешения в 100 микросекунд таким способом добиться не получить, но обычно на пользовательском вводе точность больше миллисекунды избыточна…

Кроме того если ввод происходит только в одном месте, а timeout() всегда нужен, то можно просто установить его один раз при инициализации и не отключать.

### Замечания о реализациях

На Linux `ncurses` работает аналогично коду из вопроса, с помощью `read ()` и [`poll()`](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/master/ncurses/tty/lib_twait.c#L270) (или `select ()` для некоторых других *nix-систем). Для win32con [реализация](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/master/ncurses/win32con/win_driver.c#L1516) аналогична коду из ответа **@PavelMayorov**'а: комбинация [WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx)/[PeekConsoleInput](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/peekconsoleinput)/[ReadConsoleInput](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput).

У pdcurses довольно топорная [реализация](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/pdcurses/getch.c) (псевдокод):

```
waitcount = win->_delayms / 50

for (;;) {
  if (!PDC_check_key()) {
    if (!waitcount)
       return ERR;

    waitcount--;
    msleep (50);
    continue;
  }
  return PDC_get_key();
}
```

Где [`PDC_check_key`](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/wincon/pdckbd.c#L252) и [`PDC_get_key`](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/wincon/pdckbd.c#L607) — обёртки над [`GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getnumberofconsoleinputevents) и [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) соответственно, т.е. посмотрели, пришло ли что-то, если пришло — выдали, иначе — поспали и повторили. Соответственно для pdcurses точность timeout'а составляет 50мс. По сути форма аналогична идее из ответа **@DenysSave** с добавлением задержки.

Answer (score 2):

Аналог для сокетов - одноименная функция из socket.h

Для файлов ее использовать нельзя, но можно использовать Overlapped I/O для одиночного файла и Overlapped I/O + IO Completion Port для множества файлов.

Для консоли асинхронный ввод-вывод невозможен. Но, если вам нужен просто тайм-аут, можно использовать WaitForSingleObject:

```
HANDLE conin = CreateFileW(L"CONIN$", 
    GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
if (conin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ...;

for(DWORD deadline = GetTickCount() + timeout, remaining = timeout; remaining <= timeout; remaining = deadline - GetTickCount())
{
    if (WaitForSingleObject(conin, remaining) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) break;

    DWORD n;
    INPUT_RECORD rec;
    if (!ReadConsoleInput(conin,&rec,1,&n)) break;

    if (rec.EventType == KEY_EVENT && rec.KeyEvent.bKeyDown) {
        // Тут обрабатываем нажатую клавишу
    }
}
```

Comment: Сомнительное утверждение: "Для консоли асинхронный ввод-вывод невозможен...". Наверное, смотря в каком, окружении писать. В Windows на уровне WINAPI - точно возможен. Да и на уровне стандартных рунтаймовских библиотек от Microsoft, думаю тоже возможно - слишком базовая концепция, чтобы лишать разработчиков такой возможности.

Comment: @DenysSave с msdn: [dwFlagsAndAttributes - ignored](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx). Нет способа открыть консоль с флагом FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, который требуется для асинхронного I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, приведенная функция читает из стандартного потока ввода данные, которые попали туда в течение последних 100 мсек и при этом не блокирует выполняющийся поток для ожидания очередного символа, если его в буфере нет. Основа такого чтения без блокировки - комбинация вызовов select() + getch().

В Windows точно так сделать не получится из-за того, что прямого аналога select() для стандартного устройства ввода в винде нет (есть только аналог для сокетов в winsock.h).

Поэтому вместо комбинации select() + getch() надо использовать функционал для асинхронного чтения из стандартного устройства ввода.
Например, для этого можно использовать комбинацию функций из WINAPI [GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getnumberofconsoleinputevents) + [ReadConsoleInput()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput), которую вызывать периодически и фильтроать на контролируемые события по типу:

```
DWORD n;
INPUT_RECORD rec;

if (!ReadConsoleInput(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE),&rec,1,&n))
{
    // обработка ошибки
    return;
}

if (rec.EventType!=KEY_EVENT)
{
    // отсекаем все кроме событий клавиш
    return;
}

if (!rec.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
{
    // обрабатываем нажатую клавишу
    return;
}
...
```

Comment: А смысл? Где тут тайм-аут указывать-то? Так-то для чтения без него `getch()` есть.

Comment: В примере на линуксе показан код, который работает асинхронно вводу с клавиатуры (не блокирует поток при отсутствии ввода). Для этого используется комбинация функций select() + getch(). Первая проверяет наличие символа в потоке ввода за последние 100 мсек, а вторая читает этот символ, если он есть. А если ввода нет, поток не блокируется. Я написал о том, что в Windows аналог select() из WinSock для этих целей использовать не получится. А использовать getch()  в одиночестве тоже нельзя - поток будет блокироваться. Поэтому и суть предложения - использовать функцию из WINAPI ReadConsoleInput().

Comment: Хорошо, а где в вашем примере аналогичная проверка?

Comment: Для проверки можно, например, использовать функцию WinAPI GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(). Я в примере показал, что результат вызова ReadConsoleInput() должен фильтроваться.

Comment: @DenysSave, на всякий пожарный, приведённая в вопросе функция **блокирует** поток не более чем на 100мс в ожидании новых данных, если их нет — то сразу возвращает, по прошествии интервала времени если данных нет, то возвращает ноль... Ни о каком асинхронном вводе/выводе ни в ответе, ни в вопросе речи нет, только о неблокирующем (а точнее блокирующем на определённо заданное время) — это разные вещи...